# Clicking Link Requires a Page Reload in Order to Render

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm building an application and whenever I click on a link the browser thinks it's done loading the page, but nothing renders. But, once I reload the page the page finally renders.

I'm using Rails 4.4 and Ruby 2.0.0.

I think the problem could be due to my using [pace.js](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/). I have pace.js in my asset pipeline along with it's css file.

Here is the code for my application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title id="page-title">Phoenix</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
    <meta content="" name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- begin #page-loader -->
    <div id="page-loader" class="fade in"><span class="spinner"></span></div>
    <!-- end #page-loader -->

    <!-- begin #page-container -->
    <div id="page-container" class="fade page-sidebar-fixed page-header-fixed">
        <!-- begin #header -->
        <div id="header" class="header navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <!-- begin container-fluid -->
            <div>
                <!-- begin mobile sidebar expand / collapse button -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="/clients/" class="navbar-brand"></span>Phoenix</a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-click="sidebar-toggled">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!-- end mobile sidebar expand / collapse button -->

                <!-- begin header navigation right -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <form class="navbar-form full-width">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle f-s-14">
                            <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
                            <span class="label">5</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu media-list pull-right animated fadeInDown">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Notifications (5)</li>
                            <li class="media">
                                <a href="javascript:;">
                                    <div class="media-left"><i class="fa fa-bug media-object bg-red"></i></div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h6 class="media-heading">Server Error Reports</h6>
                                        <div class="text-muted f-s-11">3 minutes ago</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="media">
                                <a href="javascript:;">
                                    <div class="media-left"><img src="/assets/user-1.jpg" class="media-object" alt="" /></div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h6 class="media-heading">John Smith</h6>
                                        <p>Quisque pulvinar tellus sit amet sem scelerisque tincidunt.</p>
                                        <div class="text-muted f-s-11">25 minutes ago</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="media">
                                <a href="javascript:;">
                                    <div class="media-left"><img src="/assets/user-2.jpg" class="media-object" alt="" /></div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h6 class="media-heading">Olivia</h6>
                                        <p>Quisque pulvinar tellus sit amet sem scelerisque tincidunt.</p>
                                        <div class="text-muted f-s-11">35 minutes ago</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="media">
                                <a href="javascript:;">
                                    <div class="media-left"><i class="fa fa-plus media-object bg-green"></i></div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h6 class="media-heading"> New User Registered</h6>
                                        <div class="text-muted f-s-11">1 hour ago</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="media">
                                <a href="javascript:;">
                                    <div class="media-left"><i class="fa fa-envelope media-object bg-blue"></i></div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h6 class="media-heading"> New Email From John</h6>
                                        <div class="text-muted f-s-11">2 hour ago</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-footer text-center">
                                <a href="javascript:;">View more</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown navbar-user">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <img src="/assets/user-13.jpg" alt="" /> 
                            <span class="hidden-xs">Adam Schwartz</span> <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInLeft">
                            <li class="arrow"></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:;">Edit Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:;"><span class="badge badge-danger pull-right">2</span> Inbox</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:;">Log Out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- end header navigation right -->
            </div>
            <!-- end container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- end #header -->

        <!-- begin #sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
            <!-- begin sidebar scrollbar -->
            <div data-scrollbar="true" data-height="1/app/00%">
                <!-- begin sidebar nav -->
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="nav-header">Navigation</li>
                    <li class="has-sub">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            <b class="caret pull-right"></b>
                            <i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i>
                            <span>Pages <span class="label label-theme m-l-5">NEW</span></span> 
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="/brands/">Brands</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/client_addresses/">Client Addresses</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/clients/">Clients</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/contacts/">Contacts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/customers/">Customers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/events/">Events</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/issues/">Issues</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/newsletters/">Newsletters</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/publications/">Publications</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/printers">Printers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!-- begin sidebar minify button -->
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="sidebar-minify-btn" data-click="sidebar-minify"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></a></li>
                    <!-- end sidebar minify button -->
                </ul>
                <!-- end sidebar nav -->
            </div>
            <!-- end sidebar scrollbar -->
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-bg"></div>
        <!-- end #sidebar -->


            <div class="content" id='content'>
                <%= yield %>
            </div>


        <!-- begin scroll to top btn -->
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-icon btn-circle btn-success btn-scroll-to-top fade" data-click="scroll-top"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
        <!-- end scroll to top btn -->
    </div>
    <!-- end page container -->

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            App.init();
            Dashboard.init();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I haven't been able to find anything so far that points to how to solve this issue.

Comment: This stinks of turbolinks... have you tried disabling turbolinks? You can take the gem out of your gemfile, or you can try replacing one of your anchor tags with a rails `link_to` and adding  `data: { no_turbolink: true }` to see if it helps.

Comment: If I turn off turbolinks it works. I'm wondering what I need to do to make it work with turbolinks. The app is a bit slower without it.